# How to delete data from Hive external table for Non-Partition column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have created an external table in Hive partitioned by client and month.

The requirement asks to delete the data for `ID=201` from that table but it's not partitioned by the `ID` column.

I have tried to do with Insert Overwrite but it's not working.

We are using Spark 2.2.0.

How can I solve this problem?

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("select * from db.table")
val newSqlDF1 = sqlDF.filter(!col("ID").isin("201") && col("month").isin("062016"))
val columns = newSqlDF1.schema.fieldNames.mkString(",")
newSqlDF1.createOrReplaceTempView("myTempTable") --34 
spark.sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db.table PARTITION(client, month) select ${columns} from myTempTable")
```

Comment: what do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: I mean not working means, It's not over writing new data. Means before run Insert overwrite suppose count is 556 and after over write count is same 556. But filter record count is 34 suppose so after execute Insert Overwrite Hive should show data  like 34 count not 556.

Comment: Maybe the problem is tat you are reading and writing to the same table at the same time. Maybe you should materalize `newSqlDF1` into another table first